# Is there anyway to restrict NUMBER of open applications on Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there anyway to restrict NUMBER of open applications on Windows similar to that of limiting the number of open tabs on Google Chrome except for Windows apps?

Applications aren't specific, I'm more focused on just how many apps I want to open at a time to avoid multitasking.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What's your use case?

Comment: Welcome to Super user. As far as I know, no (instead of maybe using a 3rd-party software). But as @spikey_richie asked, what would you want to do that?

Comment: You would find that background applications have many more windows open than you think. Look for another solution to your problem.

Comment: To conserve memory - the closest I've been able to find is "The Great Suspender" addon for Chrome. I do this on Linux with a modified IceWM, essentially freezing all background processes. Android has this setting. You could conceivably write a small program or powershell script that will kill any process over a limit... or start killing old processes as you open new ones, but it will become frustrating as random things won't work. I would suggest you switch to an Android device and use its "Background Process Limit" - as it was designed to work like this, while Windows was not.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid excessive resource use, it might be more helpful to *prevent* opening duplicate instances of an application, which can easily be done through the script below. *However*, if the issue is that you're trying to prevent yourself from multitasking because it is inefficient use of your time or a distraction, this would not help... explore behavior modification techniques.

Batch script to force single-instance use of an application (Firefox, here).

```
@echo off
tasklist | findstr "firefox.exe"
if %errorlevel% equ 0 goto running
if %errorlevel% equ 1 start " " "C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
exit

:running
exit
```

Save as a .bat file, and create a shortcut (link) to it if you prefer to use keyboard shortcuts.